# Прошу помочь с классами в typescript и angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2

Добрый день, в TS и Angular2 я дилетант, и прошу помощи у более знающих людей.
Решил старый интерфейс для магазина переписать на TS и Angular

http://pastebin.com/imJmEhhn - листинг

Собственно вопрос:
В классе `CartFront` *(строка 75 листинга)*
я получаю из отрендеренного массива `_searchres` `json` данные и отправляю их в качестве параметра в `AddCartItem`  *(строка 86 листинга)* Функция делает `push` в `private` массив класса `CartFront`. При попытке поменять в этой же функции, этого же класса поле `price_cena` у меня изменяется и `item.price_cena`. В результате изменяются данные `_searchservice`.

Вполне вероятно что я не понимаю каких-то элементарных вещей, но честно говоря, в knockoutjs у меня таких проблем не возникало.

Comment: Сделай [mcve] в планкере. Хотя очень похоже, что ты не очень понимаешь, как работают ссылочные типы, а ангуляр и тайпскрипт тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: Вы бы основы Javascript'a изучили, а? А именно как ведут себя объекты. Зачем нужно клонирование объектов и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело в понимании не TypeScript, а js. Вы передаёте в AddItem(result) - это объект. Объекты передаются по ссылке. Тоесть вы получаете не копию объекта, а тот же самый объект и изменяете его, соответственно меняется и объект _searchres. Если вам необходимо скопировать объект можете сделать так:

```
var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(b))
```

объект b будет преобразован в строку, а потом распарсится в json и уже скопируется не ссылка, а весь объект.